# SQL: Order first by table.column = 'matchingstring', then order everything else alphabetically?

Tags: sql

I'm currently using MySQL and I want to order my `book_versions` records where the `book_versions.name = 'paperback'` show up first, and then the rest of the book_versions (`book_versions.name != 'paperback'`) show. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
order by case when book_versions.name = 'paperback' then 0 else 1 end,
         book_versions.name, -- remove this line if other names should not be ordered 
         book_versions.isbn
```

See [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e1cb/1) to see the difference

in mysql, you can also use `field`

```
order by field(book_versions.name, 'paperback') DESC,
         book_versions.name ASC,
         book_versions.isbn ASC
```

Comment: Wouldn't ISBN go on the 2nd line and not the third if I wanted to order by 1. all paperbacks with isbns ASC, 2. everything else with isbns ASC?

Comment: @Edmund Well,  what do you mean by "with ISBN". The given query will order by isbn 
"inside each category" ( name)

Comment: @Edmund added a little SqlFiddle, so you may see the difference with or without second line (and take the one you need).

Comment: I mean 1. order by name = 'paperback', 2. order the paperback books by the isbn column ASC, 3. order by name ASC, 4. order those books by isbn column ASC

Comment: @Edmund so the fist version WITH the second line should be fine. But take a look at sqlfiddle in my answer, some "real" example makes usually things clearer in these cases...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN book_versions.name = 'paperback' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, -- puts paperbacks first (because paperbacks cause this to =0, which is ordered before 1)
    book_versions.name                                            -- then order alphabetically
```

Comment: Thanks Shai. It worked out well. Do you know how I could combine this ordering and add `order by book_versions.isbn ASC` to it, so that it orders by paperback + isbn ASC, and then everything else + isbn ASC

Comment: Surely just change `book_versions.name` to `book.isbn`? Otherwise, I'm misunderstanding your question